# str vs Timestamp type indices and "loc" result type

Tags: pandas

Why having a DataFrame with `str` type index for dates returns a Series, whilst Timestamp equivalent returns a DataFrame with single row?

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.dt = pd.to_datetime(df.dt, format='%Y-%m-%d')

type(df.loc['2018-01-01']) # pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
>>
```

vs

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.dt = pd.to_datetime(df.dt, format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

type(df.loc['2018-01-01']) # pandas.core.series.Series
>>
```

Comment: I think the details are mentioned [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#slice-vs-exact-match) for DatetimeIndex. String index is just usually index and `loc` returns one row, i.e. Series.

Comment: @QuangHoang yup makes sense now, basically in the first case I was giving a date index to a datetime index, which resulted in a slice for the whole date instead of a value. Thanks!